# Prove that diam(G)/apd(G) can be arbitrarily large for some connected graph G.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Here, diam(G) represents the diameter of G and apd(G) is the average pairwise distance of G. $ apd(G)= \frac{\sum_{u,v \in V} d(u,v)}{n \choose 2}$, where d(u,v) is the shortest length of path between two vertices $u$ and $v$ and $n$ is the number of vertices. I got a hint to construct a graph consists of a path and a star-shape. [Click for the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzCr.png)

My idea is to add vertex "8" that connects to only the vertex "7" and vertex "9" connects to only vertex "8", hence forming a long path, without making changes to the star-shaped part. By letting $a_{n}= \frac{diam(G_{n})}{apd{(G_n)}}$, and $c_{n}= \sum_{u,v \in V} d(u,v) = \sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}d(i,j)$  , where $n$ is the number of vertices. By recurrence relation, I got $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}=\frac{1}{2}j^{2}-\frac{1}{2}j-6$ , which only works for $j \geq 6$ and $diam(G_{n})=n-4$. By putting all into the $a_{n}$ equation and taking limits for large $n$, however I found an upper bound for $a_n$ which is $3$. May I know where did I do wrong or how the shape of the graph should look like?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the path of the graph should not only grow, the star part of the graph should also grow (possibly much faster, but you should think about that yourself). If your path has size $N$, then the graph diameter will be about $N$. But if you don't change your star part, then what happens to the average pairwise distance?

One way to think about the average pairwise distance is as follows: what if you pick two vertices at random, and look at their distance? The average outcome is the average pairwise distance. If your path is very long, and your star part doesn't change, then you will almost certainly pick two points from the path. What is the average distance between two points on the path? It's about $N/3$. So for very large $N$, your ratio will be about $N/(N/3) = 3$.